# Finding distinct values of column 1,2 along with max value of column 3

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like below:-

```
Col1  col2 Col3
 5     6    7
 5     6    8
 5     10   11
 10    12   13
 10    12   16
 15    20   1
 15    20   5
 15    8    2
 15    8    34
```

Now i need to find the rows having the distinct values of col1 and col2 along with the max value of column 3 for those valies of col1 and col2
  For eg:-

```
5    6     8
5    10    11
10   12    16
15   20    5
15   8     34
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You simply need aggregation:

```
select col1, col2, max(col3)
from yourTable
group by col1, col2
```

[Here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/group_by.php) you find some easy examples.